# NGR Regular Expression Matching

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to validate an NGR (National Grid Reference).  This must be in the format of 2 letters followed by either 4, 6, 8 or 10 digits. The first 2 letters must be either SS, ST, SW, SX or SY.  What I have so far is:

```
^[S][STWXY]\d{4}$|\d{6}$|\d{8}$|\d{10}$
```

The problem is that this seems to validate based on the two letters followed by 4 digits OR 6 digits OR 8 digits OR 10 digits

I want two letter and 4 digits OR 2 letters and 6 digits OR 2 letters and 8 digits OR 2 letters and 10 digits.

Ive not had much to do with regular expressions so I have been trying various combinations but I am obviously missing something.

Comment: You forgot to put parentheses for your OR statement `^[S][STWXY](\d{4}$|\d{6}$|\d{8}$|\d{10}$)`

Comment: sshashank124's answer is better (with the $ at the end).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply modify your regex as follows:

```
^[S][STWXY](\d{4}|\d{6}|\d{8}|\d{10})$
```

This will make the OR (`|`) operator only compare between the *digits*

Comment: Ok now I feel stupid!! Hey its early morning so I will give myself a break this once :) Many thanks!